# Change schedule date format

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm working in MS Project where the entire project duration is one hour.

My goal is to run a VBA sub when the program opens, to format the project schedule date to the "12.33 pm" style.

I've searched https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.dateformat to find a solution, but can't figure out the right syntax.

```
DateFormat(ActiveProject.Tasks) = pjDate_pjDate_hh_mmAM
```

I'd like to call this macro from my "open on macro" so the schedule date format changes to "pjDate_hh_mmAM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is the [DefaultDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa679906(v%3Doffice.11)) property of the Application object. This is the equivalent of going to File: Options, General tab: Date format.

```
Application.DefaultDateFormat = pjDate_hh_mmAM
```

You might consider capturing the current setting and restoring it later as it is an application-level setting and all projects opened will reflect this date format.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, that's exactly what I was after.